# Library for analyzing mp3s

Tags: java, audio, mp3

IS there a library for analyzing mp3 files and create some sort of hash, and then sent that hash to a db like musicbrainz.org.

Do you know a java library that could help me ? also please mention the sites that could work with that library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[music-retr is what you want](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yke/musicretrieval/).